# how to extract rising edge index pulsewidth matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using the following command to extract pulse widths:

```
 WidthHigh=pulsewidth(data(:,2),data(:,1));
```

Where `data(:,2)` is my samples vector generated from an oscilloscope and `data(:,1)` is a time stamp vector.

Is there a way to extract the indexes of the 0 crossing (or closest sample) found in `data(:,2)`? In other words, Is there a way to extract the starting index of each measured pulse width?

Also I could not understand what are `INITCROSS,FINALCROSS,MIDLEV` from the help menu. Are they the start,stop and mid level values for the rising edge? can I somehow use them for my need? the Given values where confusing when I looked at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MATLAB demo data `pulseex.mat`, if you execute this code:

```
 load('pulseex.mat','x','t')
data = [x(1:end-5);x(1:end-5)];
data = [data,data];
t = 1:1:size(data,1);
data(:,1) = t;
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2), 'k')

[WidthHigh,INITCROSS,FINALCROSS]=pulsewidth(data(:,2),data(:,1));
hold on

indices = zeros(1,numel(INITCROSS));

for ii=1:numel(INITCROSS)
    plot ( [INITCROSS(ii);INITCROSS(ii)],   ylim, 'r' )
    plot ( [FINALCROSS(ii),FINALCROSS(ii)], ylim, 'b' )
    [~, indices(ii)] = min(abs(t-INITCROSS(ii)));
end
```

You will notice that `indices` correspond to the rising edges you are looking for (red vertical lines in the following figure): `vertices = [13    42]`.
[image]

Comment: How would you extract `index` for more than a single rising edge?

Comment: I just updated the answer for multiple rising edges.

Answer (score 1):

`INITCROSS` should be what you need. Take a look at this example and see if it does what you expect:

```
t = linspace(0,1,100);
f = double(sin(5*t*pi) > .6) + randn(size(t))*.1;
figure; hold on; plot(t, f);
[~, initCross]=pulsewidth(f, t);
plot(initCross, zeros(size(initCross)), '*');
```

You can also get a very nice plot with all these terms labeled by doing

```
pulsewidth(f,t);
```

If you need the indices rather than time values, you can do (following advice from [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/218033-efficient-method-for-finding-index-of-closest-value-in-very-large-array-for-a-very-large-amount-of-e)):

```
edges = [-Inf, mean([t(2:end); t(1:end-1)]), +Inf];
inds = discretize(initCross, edges);
```

Comment: `inds = discretize(initCross, edges);` gives Undefined function 'discretize' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: @havakok `discretize` is new in R2015a. If you have the signal processing toolbox, you can do `inds = quantiz(initCross, edges);`.

Answer (score 1):

The second output argument initCross of pulsewidth is your initial zero crossing.
I created some fake data, which should make it easier to understand pulsewidth:

```
data(:,1) = 0:0.01:5; % ten sec of data
data(:,2) = cos(data(:,1)*(2*pi)); % sin wave with 1 Hz
[widthHigh,initCross]=pulsewidth(data(:,2),data(:,1));

figure
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2))
hold on
plot([initCross initCross]',repmat(ylim',1,length(initCross)),'k')
plot([initCross initCross+widthHigh]',zeros(2,length(initCross)),'r')
legend('cosine','initial 0 crossing')
```